# Strings as variable references in an R formula

Tags: r

R newbie question here. I have a list called `dbdata`. Normally I use it like this:

```
myresults <- rlm(V001 ~ V002+V003, data=dbdata)
```

However, I would like to make these references dynamic. I need to have something like this:

```
var1 <- "V001"
var2 <- "V002"
var3 <- "V003"
myresults <- rlm(var1 ~ var2+var3, data=dbdata)
```

How would I reference the variables in the context of `rlm()`? I thought perhaps something like `eval()`, but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One solution is to build the formula up using `paste()` and convert it to a formula:

```
> ## your example plus some dummy data
> var1 <- "V001"
> var2 <- "V002"
> var3 <- "V003"
> dat <- data.frame(V001 = runif(10), V002 = runif(10), V003 = runif(10))
> f <- formula(paste(var1, "~", var2, "+", var3))
```

Now we can look at `f`

```
> f
V001 ~ V002 + V003
> class(f)
[1] "formula"
```

and it really is a formula. We can now pass this into `rlm()` as the first argument:

```
> require(MASS)
> mod <- rlm(f, data = dat)
> mod
Call:
rlm(formula = f, data = dat)
Converged in 8 iterations

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        V002        V003 
  0.2725538  -0.1281576   0.1617250 

Degrees of freedom: 10 total; 7 residual
Scale estimate: 0.251
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

You can create formulas based on strings with the `reformulate` function:

```
form <- reformulate(c(var2, var3), response = var1)
# V001 ~ V002 + V003

myresults <- rlm(form, data = dbdata)
```