# Get strings recognized as column name

Tags: r, variables, reference

Forgive my newbie question. I only got started using R since a month ago. This is similar to the question here [Strings as variable references in an R formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770589/strings-as-variable-references-in-r/3770714#3770714?newreg=58a305e59ef64fb7a842fcb53c11e17b)

Since I can't comment on the answer, I'll just post it here.
I have a dataframe called `dataxl`. In this code, I am using the `crosstab()` function from [http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~william/R/crosstab.r](http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/%7Ewilliam/R/crosstab.r). (You can see the explanation of the code here http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/6975_c4943349b6174f448104a5513fed59a9.html) After running the code below, an organized version of `CrossTable()` function output will be shown:

```
    ct1 <- crosstab(dataxl, row.vars = "dataxl.tipe_merchant", col.vars = "dataxl.status", type = c("f","t"), style = "wide", addmargins = TRUE)
```

I am trying to read `row.vars` from a string variable that stores `"dataxl.tipe_merchant"`, let's call it name. I have tried the following:

```
name <- paste("dataxl.", "tipe_merchant", sep="")
f <- formula(name)
ct1 <- crosstab(dataxl, row.vars = f, col.vars = "dataxl.status", type = c("f","t"), style = "wide", addmargins = TRUE)
```

but it keeps saying something around the line

```
Error in eval(parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]]) : 
  object 'dataxl.tipe_merchant' not found
```

....something around object `'dataxl.tipe_merchant'` not found. Why is this so? Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve using formula. Please provide a reproducible example and the expected result.

Comment: Use `get(name)` rather than `formula(name)`.

Comment: @Roland it is edited

Comment: @AndrewGustar I tried it, but it gave Error in get(name) : object 'dataxl.tipe_merchant' not found

Comment: @archipelagoS: sorry if I'm misreading, but if your df is named `dataxl` shouldn't there be a `$` after it instead of a period? I mean `dataxl$tipe_merchant`. Or maybe I'm really not understanding this.

Comment: @RuiBarradas the data frame column was indeed dataxl.tipe_merchant. There was no problem running the code with just "dataxl.tipe_merchant". The only problem here was how to get row.vars from another variable instead of having to type "dataxl.tipe_merchant" directly.

Comment: I can't replicate the error. I don't have your data to try it on, so I used the example [at the link you provide](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/6975_c4943349b6174f448104a5513fed59a9.html). The code they show is `crosstab(Survey, row.vars = "Age", col.vars = "Sex", type = "f")`, which works. I can change it to `col = "age"; crosstab(Survey, row.vars = col, col.vars = "Sex", type = "f")` and it still works.

Comment: I would suggest you delete your delete your `f <- formula(name)` line  (as Roland says, not sure what that is trying to do, it seems strange) and try `crosstab(dataxl, row.vars = name, col.vars = "dataxl.status", type = c("f","t"), style = "wide", addmargins = TRUE)`, where `name <- paste("dataxl.", "tipe_merchant", sep="")` as you have it.